# Difference between class diagram and association diagrams?

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram

In my semester exams I got a question:
Draw **class diagram** and **association diagram** for the online booking of movie tickets.
I know how to draw **class diagrams** so I drew it, but I was confused regarding **association diagrams**.I took a chance and drew a diagram with my vague understanding.I only drew **class boxes** and showed **associations** between them while drawing association diagram,while in **class diagram** I showed all the relationships like *aggregation,composition,inheritance* etc.I don't know whether i was right or wrong because when I googled it I found nothing but the examples of class diagrams only.
I would appreciate deeply if anyone alleviate my confusion.thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, again after a long wait , I am going to answer my question and since it was me only who asked this, suggestions are welcome from the deep bottom of my heart.

Now , so far what I have  concluded is that ( **obviously after searching many a times on net** ) there is nothing specific like **Association diagram** as such (*I am darned of my university for asking question in this way*) . If there is anything after all its the association relationships among classifiers which can be otherwise shown as a "association diagram*. So, here is the minute difference which I could make out :

**CLASS DIAGRAMS:-** Class diagram is basically a detailed one showing classes, their interfaces , attributes and also their relationships. As for example :

[image]

While in "association diagrams" ( I am considering for now it as association diagram), classes' attributes and their internal implementation is not given much importance ,all that is shown, is the type of relationships among them.As for example :-

[image]

**NOTE**-- Any kind person who finds any more relevant information regarding this topic, please put suggestions in the comments so that I can edit my answer, for better. Any one is also free to edit my post if he or she feels its right.